# Does updating from MacOS Monterey to Ventura resolve the MacBook Air M1 issue with the trembling mouse pointer?

Tags: macos, bug

The issue is that the mouse pointer sometimes starts shaking when moved until I put the laptop in sleep mode. Have you experienced the same problem? Is it worth trying to update to the latest macOS or would it make everything worse? My current one is 12.0.1

Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe update to 12.5.1 (the most recent version) first to see whether it is fixed? It will also close some critical security issues.

Comment: Have you investigated this problem to see if the OS is the cause? Does it occur in a brand new user account, or in Safe Boot mode (hold shift at boot)? Are there any other posts by other users who have the same problem anywhere? Ventura is still in beta, and so it's too early to tell -- even if the current build fixed it, it's entire possible for the next build to break it again.

Comment: I am also experiencing this problem since I bought my M1 Macbook Air. I am using Monterey 12.6 but the problem is still there. I tried every possible solution I found online, no luck so far. This problem is not occurring not only using a Bluetooth mouse but also the onboard trackpad. Though what I realized is that in 12.6 the cursor gets fixed when I force stop the process bluetoothd. I think there is a general problem with the bluetooth of these M1 macs.

Comment: I have not seen this issue in a while on Ventura